# Using Java-generics template type in RESTful Response object via GenericEntity<List<T>>

Tags: java, rest, generics, jersey, jax-rs

I have a generic JAX-RS resource class and I have defined a generic `findAll` method

```
public abstract class GenericDataResource<T extends GenericModel> {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response findAll() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(modelClass.getSimpleName()+".findAll");
        List<T> list = query.getResultList();
        return Response.ok(new GenericEntity<List<T>>(list) {}).build();
    }
}
```

and User class:

```
public class User extends GenericModel {
    ...
}
```

And here is example subclass definition:

```
@Path("users")
public class UserResource extends GenericDataResource<User> {

    public UserResource() {
        super(User.class);
    }
}
```

I get below Exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class 
java.util.Vector, and Java type java.util.List<T>, 
and MIME media type application/json was not found exception.
```

If I replace T with a defined class such as `User` like so:

`GenericEntity<List<User>>(list)`

then it works fine.

Any idea as to how I can make it work with generic T?

Comment: The whole point of the super type token is to capture generic information that would otherwise be erased. Trying to make the token itself generic is kind of ... counterproductive.

Comment: I need "T extends GenericModel" as there are some functions which I need to access in abstract class such as T.getId()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once the source code is compiled, the (anonymous) class created by the line:

```
new GenericEntity<List<T>>(list) {}
```

uses a type variable to refer to its parent. Since type variables have no value at runtime, you can't use generics like this. You are forced to pass a so-called *type token* from the calling site. This is an example which requires the token to be passed from the caller of `findAll()`, but you could require one in the constructor and save it in an instance variable as well:

```
public abstract class GenericDataResource<T extends GenericModel> {
  public Response findAll(GenericEntity<List<T>> token) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(modelClass.getSimpleName() + ".findAll");
    List<T> list = query.getResultList();
    return Response.ok(token).build();
  }
}
```

The caller will send a token like

```
new GenericEntity<List<User>>() {}
```

If you only use non-parameterized subclasses, `findAll()` may take advantage of reflection to build the token (untested, hope you get the idea):

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response findAll() {
  Query query = em.createNamedQuery(modelClass.getSimpleName()+".findAll");
  List<T> list = query.getResultList();
  return Response.ok(new GenericEntity(list, getType())).build();
}
```

You have to implement `getType()` to return the desired type. It will be a subclass of [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) capable of denoting the type `List<DAO<User>>`

Comment: THanks Raffaele. I have a class "public class UserResource extends GenericDataResource<User>". The idea is to extend generic class without overriding its functions if standard behaviour is expected. I think in your solution each class which extends abstract class should override findAll method? Any possibility to skip overriding?

Comment: No need to override. The code calling `findAll()` must pass a token, but the method itself works without modifications. BTW, if you are **absolutely sure** that you'll only use `GenericDataResource<T>` via non-parameterized subclasses like `UserResource`, you can get the token via reflection (to restore 0-arity for `findAll()`)

Comment: Actually there is no method which explicitly calls findAll. It is called via annotations. I've edited the question to show the JAX-RS annotations.

Comment: Do you only use non-generics subclasses?

Comment: Yes, I've added to the question an example subclass User

Comment: Ok, so you can use reflection. The update uses the two-args constructor of `GenericEntity`, and the second argument is the `Type` returned by `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`. It should work, but I couldn't test it

Comment: I tried but I get: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type is incompatible with the class of the entity" exception

Comment: Sorry. I wrote a [working demo](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/a94254e8a4fbd8a09ebe). The type I passed was simply a `GenericEntity<User>`, while a `List<GenericEntity<User>>` is required. See the linked code

Comment: Nice effort. However, I get now: "com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.Vector, and Java type GenericDataResource$ListOfSomething@748a9753, and MIME media type application/json was not found" exception

Comment: Tried without success. It looks like marshalling/unmarshaling problem.

Comment: I'm setting up a complete project, however I think I made a stupid mistake. There's no need to return a `List<DAO<User>>` since you only need to represent a `List<User>`. So you may want to update your `UserResource` like I did [in the demo](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/a94254e8a4fbd8a09ebe#file-jaxrs-java-L43)

Comment: @Raffaele Kudos for perseverance. I'd like to up-vote more than once.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the answers, to read the Response object back on the client :

```
List<MyObject> list = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<MyObject>>(){}));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Response** object gets returned to client in response to request sent to a server. The Response class has Response.ResponseBuilder inner class that collects each properties set to its field of type Response.ResponseBuilder. Response.ResponseBuilder applies the Builder design pattern to construct Response Object.

The build() method is responsible to connect the chain of Response.ResponseBuilder objects formed in the course of build.
E.g.

```
Response.status(200);
```

status method return Response.ResponseBuilder after assigning STATUS

```
 Response.status(200).entity( AnyObj );
```

entity object assigns the entity( the payload returned back) of type 
 Response.ResponseBuilder and gets assigned to the Response's instance varible of. After that, status also assigns the status and returns Response.ResponseBuilder instance. The builder connects them at time of build() method call.

```
Response.status(200).entity( obj ).build();
```

Finally, the build method constructs complete(with properties set forth) Response.

Now comes the question of **GenericEntity** object. It Represents a response entity of a generic type T.

For Instance,

GenericEntity> obj = new GenericEntity>(lst) {};
 Response.status(200).entity( obj ).build();

**obj** is type of List as given above. entity method accepts **Object** type which is generic. In case, the need of specific type arises, you got to pass it as argument of GenericEntity type by which at runtime it's casted to object of Specific type.

**Practical Use**

Wanted for my Jersey Framework to respond JSON of Array type which was List object in my Java model back to client as part of Response object.

Therefore, 
 new GenericEntity>   --- casts the object/payload to List type
 new GenericEntity   ---  runtime type becomes String

---

Resource on Webservice Side

```
public Response findAllFruits(@QueryParam("frtID") String frtID ) {

         List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
         lst.add("Banana");
         lst.add("Apple");

         GenericEntity<List<String>> obj = new GenericEntity<List<String>>(lst) {};


          return Response.status(200).entity( obj ).build(); 

    }
```

**Output**
 Response sent back to client.
[
  "Banana",
  "Apple"
]

---

How to Read Response Entity

```
List<CustomType> myObj= response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<CustomType>>() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve it a made a method to return a `GenericEntity` and then a invoke it from my generic class, some thing like below:

```
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class AbstractRest<T extends IEntity> {

    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


public abstract class SmartWebServiceNEW<R extends AbstractRest<T>> {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response findAll() {
        List<T> lista = getDelegate().findAll();
        if (lista == null || lista.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
        }
        List<R> retorno = new ArrayList<R>();
        for (T it : lista) {
            retorno.add(toRest(it));
        }
        GenericEntity entity = listToGenericEntity(retorno);
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }

    protected abstract GenericEntity listToGenericEntity(List<R> restList);   
}

@Path("/something")
@RequestScoped
public class MyEntityResource extends SmartWebServiceNEW<MyEntityExtendingAbstractRest> {

 @Override
    protected GenericEntity listToGenericEntity(List<MyEntityExtendingAbstractRest> restList) {
        return new GenericEntity<List<MyEntityExtendingAbstractRest>>(restList) {
        };
    }

}
```