# is it valid to use jersey-client by making required jars to a single jar?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to use jersey-client and getting 
"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered"
I am getting this when making all required jars to single jar and removing META-INF folders. 
FYI: If i kept all jars itself then it's working fine.

So what is the solution to do so..

Comment: You need the META-INF folders, and the combination of its contents. See the comments and answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35814340/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet thank you but I don't know anything about shade plugin and it's usage

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: @peeskillet, i am just using jar command for extracting & combining them

Comment: You are going to have a tough task. You need all the files in the `META-INF/services` from all the jars. You need to combine the contents of all the files. You should really consider using Maven, and just use the shade plugin, and it will handle it for you. Otherwise it's going to be a tough task trying to do it manually. Maybe you can write a script to handle this.

Comment: @peeskillet, once again thank you for the clarification that you have given to me